# Javafx - AudioSpectrumListener not working when created outside the root file

Tags: javafx

The audio automatically stops after the music start playing (magnitudes > -60 dB) when I creates `AudioSpectrumListener` object in the `AudioVisualizer` object.

However, when I creates `AudioSpectrumListener` object in the root application file, the audio will not stop, and the content of the `updateMagnitude` method shows. May I know how could I resolve this problem?

**This is not working:**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

    AudioVisualizer line = new AudioLine(new File("testing.mp3"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(line.createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();
    line.play(); //<--Play the audio
}
```

**This is working:**

```
private AudioSpectrumListener audioSpectrumListener;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

    AudioVisualizer line = new AudioLine(new File("testing.mp3"));

    //Lines below is directly copied from the constructor of AudioVisualizer object
    audioSpectrumListener = (double timestamp, double duration, 
    float[] magnitudes, float[] phases) -> {
        line.updateMagnitude(magnitudes); };
    //-----------------------------------------

    //Lines below is directly copied from the play() method from AudioVisualizer
    line.getAudioMediaPlayer().setAudioSpectrumListener(
    audioSpectrumListener);
    line.getAudioMediaPlayer().play(); 
    //-----------------------------------------

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(line.createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

`AudioVisualizer`

```
public abstract class AudioVisualizer {
    private MediaPlayer audioMediaPlayer;
    private AudioSpectrumListener audioSpectrumListener;
    private String AUDIO_PATH;

    public AudioVisualizer(File file) {
        AUDIO_PATH = file.toURI().toString();
        audioSpectrumListener = (double timestamp, double duration, float[] magnitudes, float[] phases) -> {
            updateMagnitude(magnitudes);
        };
    }

    public abstract Parent createContent();
    public abstract void updateMagnitude(float[] magnitudes);

    public MediaPlayer getAudioMediaPlayer() {
        if (audioMediaPlayer == null) {
            Media audioMedia = new Media(AUDIO_PATH);
            audioMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audioMedia);
            audioMediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        }
        return audioMediaPlayer;
    }

    private void startAudio() {
        try {
        //If this line below is commented, the audio will play but the listener will not function
        getAudioMediaPlayer().setAudioSpectrumListener(
            audioSpectrumListener);
        getAudioMediaPlayer().play();
        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e); }
    }

    public void play() {
        this.startAudio();
    }
```

Comment: What are `AudioVisualizer` and `AudioLine`? These are not part of the standard JavaFX library... Is everything getting garbage collected in the code block that doesn't work? So if you make `line` an instance variable instead of a local variable, does it fix the problem. Just a blind guess as I don't know what the classes are that you're using.

Comment: Really appreciated your help! Making `line` an instance variable does work. But may I know why?

Comment: Because otherwise it gets garbage collected, as there are no references to it once the `start` method exits. Presumably the `MediaPlayer` is written in such a way that the media itself will not prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Then why is attaching AudioSpectrumListener directly to the `line` in `start` method will allow it to work (it still works even if I made AudioSpectrumListener a local variable in `start` method)

Comment: Yeah, no clue. I'm guessing about the gc, but if that's correct it's hard to diagnose as you never really know when it is going to kick in. You can experiment with adding an event handler that calls `System.gc()` to see if you can force it to break when the handler is invoked.

Comment: @James_D I realised that **only** when I pass local variable `line` to another method which **sets a window close eventHandler** for primaryStage. (Stop the audio when stage is closed), `line` will somehow not get garbage collected. Much appreciation for you help! Can you help to answer the question(about instance variable) so that I can close the question.